# Approximation ratio of randomized rounding for integral multi-commodity flow

Tags: approximation-algorithms, randomized-algorithms, chernoff-bound, multicommodity-flow

In [1], Raghavan and Thompson showed that we can use randomized rounding to approximate integral multi-commodity flow and routing with congestion. The result is that suppose the optimal solution is $W$, we can obtain, a solution $\le W+\sqrt{W\cdot O(\log n)}$ if $W\ge \Omega(\log n)$ with high probability.

However, in subsequent literature, e.g., [2], it is said that [1] achieves an approximation ratio of $O(\log n/ \log\log n)$. How to transform the original result to this $O(\log n/ \log\log n)$ bound?

The proof in [1] basically uses the Chernoff bound, $\mathbb{P}[X\ge (1+\delta)W]\le \exp(-\delta^2 W/3)$, by setting $\delta=\sqrt{O(\log n)/W}$. I try to set $\delta=O(\log n/\log \log n)$ but this seems to not work.

[1] Raghavan and Thompson. [Randomized rounding: A technique for provably good algorithms and algorithmic proofs](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1007/BF02579324).
[2] Chuzhoy et al. [Hardness of Routing with Congestion in Directed Graphs](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Esanjeev/papers/stoc07_diredpwc.pdf).

Comment: This is standard material. It may help you to see the O(log n/log log n) approximation for congestion minimization. See book of Raghavan-Thomson or Chapter 5 in Williamson-Shmoys book or Chapter 7 of my notes https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs583/fa2021/approx-algorithms-lecture-notes.pdf. You can then adapt it for the maximization problem.

Comment: @Chandra Chekuri Got it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I meant book of Motwani-Raghavan on randomized algorithms, not book of Raghavan-Thompson.